# What does "their cash flows get up to speed" mean?

Tags: meaning

So, here's the sentence. I'll put the sentence before it as well.

> Too many businesses start their business without enough capital. They just don't have enough money in the bank to support them while *their cash flows get up to speed*.

I especially have a hard time understanding the italicized part.

Comment: When you start a business, your cash flow (cash in + cash out) is generally slow because you don't sell much. It takes some time for the cash flow to normalize and be speedy enough to take care of your cost and expenses. Up to speed means "operating at full speed".

Comment: by "cash out" you mean the money you have to spend for your business to keep running

Comment: Yes, cash in is the money you earn from selling products and service. Cash out is the opposite, i.e., the money you spend to keep your company as a going concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cash flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_flow) refers here to a business receiving payments from customers, which they can then use to pay their expenses. When a business starts, the receiving end tends to start slowly; it takes a while to get to *the desired rate* for a healthy company, which is exactly what [up to speed](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+speed) means. To get through this period, you'll need start-up capital.